# Internet routing through linux speeds down

Tags: linux, networking, performance, fiber

I'm having the most odd problem:
I'm providing internet routing for a network of pcs through a server based on linux. I used a broadband modem and everything worked fine.

Now, to the question, I got an optic fiber modem (*PON* **Huawei Echolife HG8240**) with the same speed as the broadband modem, but connecting the PON directly to one pc give's me full speed (10 mb/s up and down) but connecting the *PON* to a network adapter on the linux box slows down the internet connection to the PON at a rate that it can't even reach the 1mb/s (downloading, because uploading works at 10mbps at any link speed).

I was amazed and still am, but tuning and tweaking I found that using **ethtool** and setting the network adapter connected to the PON to **10 mb full duplex** raises the throughoutput to 8,5mb/s. Still it's not the 10+ mb I get connecting it directly to one windows pc so... I'm at a loss here.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Problem may be negotiation only, Use the ethtool to set the speed to maximum supported by the port on modem, and set **autoneg on**.

Comment: That's the thing, on windows the port on the modem it's set for 1 Gbps, on linux, autonegotiating it sets on 1Gbps too. But on linux neither 1 Gbps nor 100 mbps will download at a rate greater that 1mbps

Comment: Verify there are **tc**, **wondershaper** , or even iptables burst-size not running.

Comment: I checked, but it has to be something else, because just setting the network adapter link to 10mb boosts up the download speed to 8mbps. Setting it on 100 or 1000 and the download rate can't reach 1mbps.

Answer (score 0):

Well, odd problem, odd solution. The whole problem was a rule on the firewall that prevented big packets from coming down the line:
*"-j TCPMSS  --clamp-mss-to-pmtu"*
Removed that from the firewall and worked like a charm.

Thanks Anirudh for your comments